# I'm getting an error when I try to upload in GraphQL: "POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys."

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-upload

My code is correct, but I don't know what's happening, I need to upload it with graphQL but I can't, my resolver code looks like this:

```
import { Resolver, Query, Mutation, Arg } from "type-graphql";

import { GraphQLUpload, FileUpload } from "graphql-upload-ts";

@Resolver()
export class CategoryResolver {
    @Mutation(() =\> String)
    async uploadImage(@Arg("file", () =\> GraphQLUpload) file: FileUpload) {
    console.log({ file });

        return "message";

    }
}
```

I already changed the content-type of my apollo server sandbox to multipart/form-data and it gives this error: "POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys." and when I change to application/json this error occurs: "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" I know that the request has to be made in the multipart/form-data format. I'm adding all the fields correctly, I don't know what's happening, the versions are: "@apollo/server": "^4.9.5", "graphql-upload-ts": "^2.1.0", "type- graphql": "2.0.0-beta.1"

[Apollo Sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7IDr.png)